# Both & and &amp; do not work when configuring a JDBC URL with more than one parameter in Spring Framework petclinic

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

When trying to use spring-framework-petclinic-master app in STS with the jetty:run-war -P MySQL option I need to pass several parameters in the MySQL JDBC URL no typical option works, neither

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/petclinic?useUnicode=true&amp;useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&amp;useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC
```

or

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/petclinic?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
```

Did work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to double escape the URL using CDATA so the XML validator ignores the & and then use & as the JDBC string is processed with XML validation.
The following did work:

```
<properties>
        <db.script>mysql</db.script>
        <jpa.database>MYSQL</jpa.database>
        <jdbc.driverClassName>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</jdbc.driverClassName>
        <jdbc.url><![CDATA[jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/petclinic?useUnicode=true&amp;useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&amp;useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC]]></jdbc.url>
        <jdbc.username>petclinic</jdbc.username>
        <jdbc.password>petclinic</jdbc.password>
    </properties>
```

Comment: I find it really weird that this is necessary, I don't think the second level should be necessary. Is it possible that this is just a symptom of some additional processing or some other component in your system? Or could you reproduce this with a simple, minimal spring-data-jpa app? Also a "simple" `&amp;amp;` should also work in your case then you could leave out the `CDATA.

Comment: amp amp? I rather go with the CDATA. But if you want I can try that also. But I am sure what I am saying.

Comment: Your option does also work, add it as response if you want and I can accept it